# How to access specific cell in UICollectionView after scrolling when page loads?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am trying to build a timeline like so:

[image]

Each cell in the timeline represents a month so May is the last cell in the horizontal collectionView. What I want is when the collectionView loads, it auto-scrolls over to may if its not already visible then calls a specific function on the cell to draw the arrow. The code that I am using to try to do that is below.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timeline.register(UINib(nibName: "TimelineMonthViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TimelineMonthViewCell")
    self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PostCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PostCollectionViewCell")
    pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

    UserService.posts(for: User.current,tagString: self.selectedTagTitles.first!) { (postStuff) in

        self.posts = postStuff.0
        self.postIds = postStuff.1
        self.timeline.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.timeline.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.firstPostDate = self.posts.first?.timeStamp
        self.currentPostDate = self.posts.last?.timeStamp
    }
}

override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
    let firstPostDate = self.posts.first?.timeStamp
    let diff = self.posts.last?.timeStamp.months(from: (firstPostDate?.startOfMonth())!)
    //self.currentPostMonth = diff
    let monthCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: diff!, section: 0)
    self.timeline.scrollToItem(at: monthCellIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    let months = self.posts.last?.timeStamp.months(from: (self.posts.first?.timeStamp.startOfMonth())!)
    print("cells are",self.timeline.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    print(months,"cell months")
    if let optionalCell = self.timeline.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: months!, section: 0)) {
        let cell = optionalCell as! TimelineMonthViewCell
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self.currentPostDate!)
        cell.drawArrow(day: day)
    } else {
        print("cell out of range")
    }
}
```

This almost works except for two issues.

First, the initial cell flashes before it auto-scrolls to the last one. I think this is because I am using viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear. However when I use viewWillLoad, I get the app crashing with an error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8)`

Second, the printed self.timeline.indexPathsForVisibleItems are: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]]. So its looking at the first 5 instead of the last 5 that it just scrolled to. And then it cannot find the cell: "cell out of range" because the index is about 28 (the last cell).

So how can I get it to auto-scroll to the last cell and find it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set these lines at their current place

```
self.timeline.dataSource = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
self.timeline.delegate = self
self.collectionView.delegate = self
```

may be better in top of the `viewDidLoad` , to take benefit of the first automatic reload when the vc is loaded , also in their place insert

```
self.timeline.reloadData()
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

you may insert the scroll code inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {  }
```

or inside `ViewDidAppear` if your current for loop isn't asynchronous

Comment: can you show the code you are thinking of. I can't move the dataSource and delegates to the top of viewDidLoad because my posts object hasn't been created yet. Also I removed the async dispatch to simplify the question if you wanna look at the updated code...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to move the scroll code to `viewWillAppear`. That way it is done before the view is displayed but after everything is ready to view.

```
override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
    let firstPost = self.posts.first?.timeStamp
    let firstOfFirstMonth = firstPost?.startOfMonth()
    let diff = self.posts.last?.timeStamp.months(from: firstOfFirstMonth!)
    //self.currentPostMonth = diff
    let monthCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: diff!, section: 0)
    self.timeline.scrollToItem(at: monthCellIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: This crashes my app with the error code: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8) on this line:         self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)

Comment: Hmm. Try moving it do viewDidAppear. With any luck you won't see it update.

Comment: that does work! However I am still having the same issue with the cells not being found so the arrow cannot be drawn

Comment: if you checkout the updated question you can see that I incorporated your advice and am having issues still with the cell Indexes not being found in viewDidAppear. In fact the indexesForVisibleCells seems to print the original indexes (the ones before the scroll happened)

Comment: You need to handle the drawing in `cellForItemAt` which is really a second question. Post it as a different question and I will try to answer it.